# Storing the object of derived class as a base class variable. What is OOP term for this ?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, we often use a initializing syntax that a instance of a base class is initializing with its inherited child class like this:

```
Control BTN = new Button();
```

Now my question is just that, what is the formal name of this kind of initializing?

Comment: I don't think there is a name for that... it's just an application of inheritance.

Comment: @Thomas, assigning a `Derived` reference to a `Base` reference has more to do with [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) than inheritance IHMO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, upvote because you apparently beat me to the reference to polymorphism while I was typing my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C# specification, it is called *simple assignment* with an *implicit reference conversion*.

> **7.16.1 Simple assignment**
>
> In a simple assignment, the right operand must be an expression of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of the left operand.
>
> ...
>
> The run-time processing of a simple assignment of the form x = y consists of the following steps:
>
> - ...
> - y is evaluated and, if required, converted to the type of x through an implicit conversion (§6.1).
>
> **6.1.6 Implicit reference conversions**
>
> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> - ...
> - From any class-type S to any class-type T, provided S is derived from T.

Answer (score 3):

The most concise term I can think of is polymorphic instantiation, or polymorphic initialization. That seems to capture the necessary elements without writing a whole sentence. Not aware of a formal term, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not base class *instance initializing*. This is the inherited class instance initializing and *referencing* this instance via variable of base class type. You can call it `assignment value to variable`. No special name.